# Flutter sort a list into nested widget of TreeNode

Tags: flutter

I have a json array returned by api as follows:

```
"data": [
        {
            "id": "7",
            "parent": "1",
        },
        {
            "id": "8",
            "parent": "7",
        },
        {
            "id": "9",
            "parent": "8",
        },
        {
            "id": "10",
            "parent": "7",
        },

    ]
```

Is there a way that i can sort this data into a treeview as in [flutter_simple_treeview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_simple_treeview) so that it looks like below? I have tried using map toList but can't seem to figure out the algorithm.

```
1
 -7
   -8
     -9
 -10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_simple_treeview/flutter_simple_treeview.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final data = <Map<String, dynamic>>[
    {
      "id": "7",
      "parent": "1",
    },
    {
      "id": "8",
      "parent": "7",
    },
    {
      "id": "9",
      "parent": "8",
    },
    {
      "id": "10",
      "parent": "7",
    },
  ];

  String rootNode() {
    var r = data.firstWhere((e) => !data.any((ee) => ee["id"] == e["parent"]));
    return r["parent"];
  }

  TreeNode buildNode(String e) {
    return TreeNode(
        content: Text(e),
        children: data.where((element) => element["parent"] == e).map((element) => buildNode(element["id"])).toList());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TreeView(nodes: [buildNode(rootNode())]);
  }
}
```

Edit: to answer the question from Fawaz - if you wanted to show more complex object (id, parent, name, year), then your data would look something like this:

```
final data = <Map<String, dynamic>>[
    {
      "id": "7",
      "parent": "1",
      "name": "some name",
      "year": 2023
    },
...
```

So now, pass the entire map to buildNode function, and in content - build any widget you want with the data.

```
TreeNode buildNode(Map<String,dynamic> m) {
    return TreeNode(
        content: Row(children: [Text(m.id),Text(m.parent), Text(m.name), Text(m.year)]) ,
        children: data.where((element) => element["parent"] == m.id).map((element) => buildNode(element)).toList());
  }
```

and of course, this needs to change:

```
Map<String, dynamic> rootNode() {
    var r = data.firstWhere((e) => !data.any((ee) => ee["id"] == e["parent"]));
  
    return {
      "id": r,
      "parent": null,
      "name": null,
      "year": null
    };
  }
```

And how it works? It first need to find the root node; this is where it starts. After that, for root node it will find all children, and build a node for them. And then recursively calls buildNode for child of their own and so on.

Comment: Can you explain how this works? Like suppose there are more fields (id, parent, name, year), how can i display something other than the id (name or year) as the node text

Comment: Updated my answer with more details for your question, I hope it helps.

Comment: Ha thats perfect, Thanks. But what if my data does not have a single root node structure. Like for example there could be 5 children with the parent "0", and I just wanna show the five children as the root nodes.

Comment: Then your function should return all root nodes in a list, and then you add each tree for each independent node.